# Kubernetes copy image data to volume mounts

Tags: kubernetes

I need to share a directory between two containers: myapp and monitoring and to achieve this I created an emptyDir: {} and then volumeMount on both the containers.

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name:  shared-data
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        volumeMounts:
          - name:  shared-data
            mountPath:  /etc/myapp/
      - name: monitoring
        volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-data
            mountPath: /var/read
```

This works fine as the data I write to the shared-data directory is visible in both containers. However, the config file that is created when creating the container under /etc/myapp/myapp.config is hidden as the shared-data volume is mounted over /etc/myapp path (overlap).

How can I force the container to first mount the volume to /etc/myapp path and then cause the docker image to place the myapp.config file under the default path /etc/myapp except that it is the mounted volume thus allowing the config file to be accessible by the monitoring container under /var/read?

Summary: let the monitoring container read the /etc/myapp/myapp.config file sitting on myapp container.

Can anyone advice please?

Comment: A container has to run `cp` in some form itself, either in its own entrypoint or in an init container.  Kubernetes never copies files into a volume on its own (this is different behavior from Docker).

Comment: I am not tied up to using a Volume - all I want is ... the data under /etc/myapp which has default config file (written by the image) and new config files (as myapp container is running) should be available for the monitoring container to pick up.

Comment: @BuggyB Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: No, I abandoned the above now. instead of using a sidecar that needed the above to work, I embedded the binary (for metric scrapping) directly on the main myapp  container, which can directly read from  /etc/myapp/*. This is not a good solution as when ever I scale myapp, the monitoring will also scale but for my scenario, I'll be not scaling up - single container myapp.

Answer (score 1):

Can you mount shared-data at /var/read in an init container and copy config file from /etc/myapp/myapp.config to /var/read?

Comment: 1. Mount shared-data volume to /var/read - Yes
2. But how can I copy /etc/myapp/myapp.config on MyApp container to /var/read on Monitoring container?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) with [SubPaths](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath).

> A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in
> key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables,
> command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a volume.

> Sometimes, it is useful to share one volume for multiple uses in a
> single pod. The `volumeMounts.subPath` property specifies a sub-path
> inside the referenced volume instead of its root.

ConfigMaps can be used as volumes. The `volumeMounts` inside the `template.spec` are the same as any other volume. However, the volumes section is different. Instead of specifying a `persistentVolumeClaim` or other volume type you reference the configMap by name. Than you can add the `subPath` property which would look something like this:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name:  shared-data
    mountPath:  /etc/myapp/
    subPath: myapp.config
```

Here are the resources that would show you how to set it up:

- [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/): official docs
- [Using ConfigMap SubPaths to Mount Files](https://dev.to/joshduffney/kubernetes-using-configmap-subpaths-to-mount-files-3a1i): step by step guide
- [Mount a file in your Pod using a ConfigMap](https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/02/10/kubernetes-mount-file-pod-with-configmap/): supplement